# AS3: ByteArray and BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, copy, arrays, bitmapdata

I'm doing a simple test. I want to write BitmapData into a ByteArray. I'm trying to do this with writeObject() and readObject(). Read object seems to have trouble making sense of the BitmapData.

```
var byteArray : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var _cache : BitmapData = new BitmapData( 640, 480, true, 0x000000 );
var _blank : BitmapData = new BitmapData( 640, 480, true, 0x000000 );

byteArray.writeObject( _blank );
byteArray.position = 0;
_cache = byteArray.readObject() as BitmapData;
trace( _cache ); // Traces null
```

Can anyone clear this up for me? I can't make sense of what's going wrong with readObject();

I know I can do this getPixels() and setPixels(), but I'd like to treat the object as an object here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use `BitmapData::getPixels` and `BitmapData::setPixels` ... writing class instances to a ByteArray as such never completely works as expected ... try with Sprites ... :) ... this is mostly due to the fact, that the default implementation somehow only writes an object's property to the `IDataOutput` (`ByteArray` or `Socket`) ... the pixels are not a property of the `BitmapData` in that sense ... the `BitmapData` is just an ActionScript wrapper, that exposes an interface to some internal flash player data structure ...

you should write an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for `BitmapData`, that implements [`IExternalizable`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html), so that you have control, over what happens ... essentially, you will only need to read/write the dimensions, and the actual pixel payload ... maybe the transparent-flag ... remember to use [`registerClassAlias`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()) ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Really interesting. Awesome answer, as usual. Thank you! I'll experiment with this.